# how to drop shadow on illustrator stroke only

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I just drop shadow on stroke like the rectangle in the picture?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that the picture and the question are related in the terms used in the question.

If you want to add some effect to stroke -

You invoke Appearance panel, Select Stroke, press on "fx" and add Drop shadow effect:

[image]

[image]

[image]